# Como puedo guardar la celda tipo número "1,200.24" con este valor en el excel generado con JAVA?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Estoy intentando guardar números pero se me guardan como formato general,
Yo primero formateo el número como lo quiero:
Este número entrar por paramtro: 1200.24:

```
public static String formatNumber(double num) {
        String valor;
        DecimalFormat formateador = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##");
        valor = formateador.format(num);
        return valor;
    }
```

Luego tengo unos método que comprueba si es un entero o double o string (En este caso una string)

```
String valor = formatNumber(Double.parseDouble("1200.24"));
if(comprobarInt(valor)) {
    int numInt = Integer.parseInt(valor);
    System.out.println("Entero: "+numInt);
    celda.setCellValue(numInt);
} else if(comprobarDouble(valor)) {
    double numDouble = Double.parseDouble(valor);
    System.out.println("Double: "+numDouble);
    celda.setCellValue(numDouble);
} else {
    System.out.println("Cadena: "+valor);
//  celda.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);//Esto he probado y no funciona
    celda.setCellValue(valor);
}
```

Esto me devolverá una string con el siguiente valor "1.200,24".
cómo puedo guardar esa celda tipo número.

Comment: Hace muchísimo tiempo que hago este tipo de cosas pero estoy casi seguro de que el manejo del formato con que se muestra el número en la celda lo hace Excel y no Java. Por lo tanto creo que debes pasar el valor de la celd sin formatear. Además, no has dicho cuál es el problema que tienes con ese código.

Comment: Hola @E.Betanzos el problema era ese, que no sabía como guardar ese número y que en el excel me salga como formato número, pero ya lo he conseguido.     `private CellStyle formatNumberCell() {
  CellStyle style = wk.createCellStyle();
     style.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#,##0.00"));
  return style;
 }` con eso me fue suficiente, wk es un objeto de HSSFWorkbook.

Comment: te recomiendo que agregues ese comentario como respuesta para que puedas marcarla con correcta (en unos 3 días) y ganar reputación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private CellStyle formatNumberCell() { 
   CellStyle style = wk.createCellStyle(); 
   style.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#,##0.00")); return style;
}
```

con eso me fue suficiente, wk es un objeto de HSSFWorkbook.

y luego se llamas llamo al método formatCellNumberCell() y se lo aplico a la celda,
Ejemplo:

```
 HSSFCell celda;
celda.setCellStyle(formatCellNumberCell());
```